# Capacitor - About Dissipation Factor and Ripple current (mA/rms)

Tags: capacitor

I m actually reading a capacitor datasheet which specifies the ripple current and the dissipation factor. This one:

https://datasheet.octopart.com/CA035M0100REH-0607-Yageo-datasheet-12513699.pdf

[image]

As you can see the ripple current and the dissipation factor are given for a frequency. But clearly I will not operate at this frequency... And I would like to know how the ripple current (which is adviced to do not reduce the life time of the capacitors) evolve in function of the frequency? Same question for the dissipation factor.

Thank you very much and have a nice day! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to use a different capacitor data sheet to more easily explain this. Consider a 100 uF 35 volt capacitor such as [this one](https://uk.farnell.com/panasonic/eeefp1v101ap/cap-100-f-35v-radial-smd/dp/1539512) from Farnell: -

[image]

The important things to note are in red above. It has a quoted ESR of 0.16 ohms and the dissipation factor is calculated as: -

$$DF = \dfrac{\text{ESR}}{X_C} = \text{ESR}\cdot 2\cdot\pi\cdot f\cdot C$$

<sub>Corrected below - error in decimal places impacted the words and the analysis hence, there are changes.</sub>

If you plug in the numbers (at 120 Hz) you get a dissipation factor of 0.01206 and this is ten times lower than the quoted figure of 0.12. If you calculated ESR using a DF of 0.12 you get 1.59 ohms at 120 Hz. Given that we know that the real series resistance is 0.16 ohms, 1.43 ohms of the 1.59 ohms at 120 Hz is due to dielectric losses.

Personally, I like to see dielectric loss placed in parallel with the capacitor so, if you want, you can [convert the series 1.43 ohms](http://wcalc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/parallel_rc.cgi?Cs=100&wc_unit_menu_0_0=uF&Rs=1.43&wc_unit_menu_1_0=Ohm&Qs=8.28932&Cp=98.5655&Rp=111.541&wc_unit_menu_2_0=Ohm&Qp=8.28932&freq=120&wc_unit_menu_3_0=Hz&stype=use_R&s2p=Series+To+Parallel) to a parallel resistance of 124.44 ohms and your equivalent capacitor becomes this at 120 Hz: -

[image]

This makes more sense to me because at low frequencies, the dielectric will have a large voltage across it whereas at 100 kHz, due to the capacitive reactance being so low, the dielectric will not be presented with a large voltage at the specified ripple current.

> *But clearly I will not operate at this frequency*

Well, my advice is to find a component that covers the operating frequency you want for the ripple current. The Panasonic device has a ripple current specified up to 100 kHz and I would much rather trust this one than one that is unspecified at higher frequencies.

> *I would like to know how the ripple current (which is advised to do
> not reduce the life time of the capacitors) evolve in function of the
> frequency ?*

The ripple current is defined by your usage of the capacitor in your circuit. If you can't estimate it, run a simulation and get an answer that way. I can't tell you what ripple current your circuit has; there are certain things that you have to calculate based on your knowledge or your circuit.

> *Same question for the dissipation factor*

The formula for DF is given higher up. Note that ESR is defined at 100 kHz so this is a decent benchmark for quality if you are using high frequencies. The device in the question is more suited as a bulk capacitor in a regular transformer-bridge rectifier power supply because 120 Hz is the ripple frequency when the AC is at 60 Hz.

Regards the lifetime of the capacitor, the one in the question is rated at 85 °C whereas the one I linked is rated at 105 °C and that usually means that the Panasonic device will endure 4 times longer. Every 10 °C above the working ambient temperature doubles the endurance time.

Comment: Hi Andy ! It is a pleasure to read you again ! "I would like to know how the ripple current (which is advised to do not reduce the life time of the capacitors) evolve in function of the frequency ?" This not what I wanted to say, In the datasheet it is specified a maximum ripple current for the capacitor can tolerate but it is defined at a certain frequency ... and actually I do not know if at a higher frequency the ripple current is lower or higher. Is it more clear ?

Comment: Interesting point about the temperature and life time relation

Comment: The ripple current in the Panasonic capacitor is specified (note 2) at 100 kHz. Is this high enough for you. As for the datasheet in your question, there is no doubt to me - I wouldn't expect it to perform at 100 kHz. Everything about it says: 120 Hz.

Comment: Ok :) And If I used your capacitor at 50 kHz, shoud I think that the maximal ripple current will be the same than the one at 100 kHz ?

Comment: @Jess The ripple current limit is based on \$I^2R\$ losses where R = ESR so, given that ESR is constant, the answer is yes. You forgot to `@andy` me hence the delayed reply.

Comment: Np :) Thank you ! But the ESR is not constant in function of the frequency as you showed into the formula that you give.

Comment: ESR is constant but DF and Xc vary With frequency @Jess

Comment: Wooow ! I do not know ... Thank you ! So obtaining the ESR @ 100 kHz from this datasheet is impossible ... According to Wikipedia : "Dissipation factor will vary depending on the dielectric material and the frequency of the electrical signals" for those who would have some doubts : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissipation_factor

Comment: For your capacitor you can't predict ESR at anything other than 120 Hz but, for the capacitor I linked, the ESR and DF are quoted at 100 kHz and, as frequency drops, ESR isn't going to get any worse.

Comment: What is really not clear from the datasheet is that 0.16 Ohm is specified as ESR and if I understand what you are telling me it represents the serie resistance... An other thing weird to me, is that the series resistance is lower for higher capacitance and as regard as how are built the capacitor, it sounds weird to me ? isn't it ?

Comment: In any case, your explanation is really interesting ! So thank you ! You taught me so many things !

Comment: @Jess I am just mad with myself for getting the decimal places wrong and making a partial answer that could have originally been misleading. Nobody spotted it but me (luckily) but it needed to be fixed.

Comment: Nice to you ! :)

Comment: The 0.16 ohm is the series resistance at 100 kHz. This is what the manufacturer will measure. The series resistance becomes lower the more volume in the case roughly so, smaller capacitors have a smaller case volume. It's just approximate of course.

Comment: Ok finally that s sound good !

Comment: Thank you so much again :)